# Prime $z$-filters

Tags: general-topology, filters

> A nonempty subfamily  $\mathcal{F}$ of $Z(X)$  is called $z$-filter on   $X$  provided that
>
> 1. $ \emptyset \not \in \mathcal{F}$
> 2. If $z_{1} , z_{2} \in \mathcal{F}$  , then $z_{1} \cap z_{2} \in \mathcal{F}$
> 3. If $ z \in \mathcal{F} , z^{*} \in Z(X) , z^{*} \supset z$ , then $ z^{*} \in \mathcal{F}$
>
> **The family $Z[ C(X)] =Z(X) =\{ Z(f) : f \in C \} $ is all zero-sets in $X$.
>   $Z(f) = \{ x \in X : f(x) = 0 \}$**

So, my question is:

> The following are equivalent for a $z$-filter $\mathcal{F}$.
>
> 1. $\mathcal{F}$ is prime.
> 2. whenever the union of two zero-sets is all of $X$, at least one of them belongs to $\mathcal{F}$.
> 3. Given $z_{1},
>     z_{2} \in Z(X) $, there exist $z \in \mathcal{F} $ such that one of $z
>     \cap z_{1} , z \cap z_{2}$ contains the other.

Comment: Filter is usually defined on $\mathcal P(X)$ or something like that. The meaning of your $Z(X)$ is entirely unclear to me.

Comment: @CaveJohnson If $X$ is a topological space and $f$ is a real valued continuous function on $X$, the zeroset of $f$, $Z(f) = \{x \in X: f(x) = 0\}$ is a closed subset of $X$. All possible $Z(f)$ form the set $Z(X)$ which is a sublattice of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ consisting of these closed sets. The OP is considering filters in this lattice, which are called $z$-filters.

Answer (score 2):

2 $\Rightarrow$ 3: If $z_1,z_2\in Z(X)$ then we have $f_1,f_2\in C(X)$ such that $Z(f_1)=z_1$ and $Z(f_2)=z_2$. For $x\in X$, let $g_1(x)=\max\{0,|f_1(x)|-|f_2(x)|\}$, $g_2(x)=\max\{0,|f_2(x)|-|f_1(x)|\}$. Then $g_1,g_2\in C(X)$ and $Z(g_1)\cup Z(g_2)=X$, hence 2. implies that there is some $z\in\{Z(g_1),Z(g_2)\}\cap\mathcal{F}$. If $z=Z(g_1)$ then $z\cap z_1=\{x\in X\colon 0=|f_1(x)|\le|f_2(x)|\}$ and $z\cap z_2=\{x\in X\colon|f_1(x)|\le|f_2(x)|=0\}$, hence $z\cap z_2\subseteq z\cap z_1$. Similarly, if $z=Z(g_2)$ then $z\cap z_1\subseteq z\cap z_1$.

3 $\Rightarrow$ 2: If $z_1,z_2\in Z(X)$ and $z_1\cup z_2=X$ then by 3. there is some $z\in\mathcal{F}$ such that (without a loss of generality) $z\cap z_1\subseteq z\cap z_2$. We have $z=z\cap(z_1\cup z_2)=z\cap z_2\subseteq z_2$, hence $z_2\in\mathcal{F}$.

Together with Henno's answer we obtain the equivalence.

Comment: You don't need $3 \implies 2$ as I did the other steps for the "circle".

Answer (score 1):

$1 \Rightarrow  2$ is clear by the definition of a prime filter in $Z(X)$ as $X \in Z(X)$ ($0$-function) and $X \in \mathcal{F}$ for any $z$-filter $\mathcal{F}$ (axiom 3).

$3\Rightarrow 1$ is also clear: suppose $z_1 \cup z_2 \in \mathcal{F}$ for some $z_1,z_2 \in Z(X)$. We apply 3. and get $z \in \mathcal{F}$ such that (say) $z \cap z_1 \subseteq z \cap z_2$. Then:

$$\mathcal{F} \ni z \cap (z_1 \cup z_2) = (z \cap z_1)\cup (z \cap z_2) = z \cap z_2 \subseteq z_2$$ so that $z_2\in \mathcal{F}$ by axiom 3. That the left hand side is in $\mathcal{F}$ follows from axiom 2 of $z$-filters. We thus see that $\mathcal{F}$ is prime.

I'll have to think some more on why 2. implies 3. to get equivalence.